# D3.nest returning different object propery names in Safari and Firefox

Tags: d3.js, drupal-7

I've been struggling with for some time but discovered that d3.nest returned an object with different property names in Safari and Firefox (maybe also Chrome). In Safari the property names were Key and Values, but in Firefox Key and Value. (I just tested again and both return Value.) I can't see the Chrome console.log messages so I am not sure what is being returned but the results are different.

D3 version d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js

row stringify - > {"key":"event","value":{"10":15,"11":21,"12":14,"13"

Can anyone suggest what is happening?

Comment: I should add that the same code would work in Safari and not in Firefox. I note that there are cases when d3.nest returns "value" and some "values" but the same code should be consistent (IMO).

Comment: Also, if anyone knows how to use the console window I'd really appreciate it. I have created 2 versions of my page - one uses "value" and the other uses "values". The "value" version works in Safari and Firefox but neither work in Chrome. One time I saw the name "\value" but I haven't been able to recreate it.

Comment: I am doing something that is causing the property value to return to "values" in one version of the code. No idea what.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually the property name settled down to "values". Possibly one of the d3 scripts I eventually removed was causing the problem.